# Creating a Python Abstract Enum or an Enum hierarchy

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I have a library project and several consumer projects, that make use of the central library functions.
The library project contains an Enum which must be specified in the consuming project by adding Enum entries/values.

Problem: I have a common service function in the library project which currently can't instantiate concrete Enums defined in the consumer project.

I understand why the exceptions occurs (440 is not a member of AbstractProgrammCode; inheritance is disregarded).

What are my (cleanest) options?

**"Super" Enum in lib project**

```
import logging
from enum import Enum

class AbstractProgrammCode(Enum):

    @staticmethod
    def create_with(string: str):
        if not string or not string.strip().isnumeric():
            raise ValueError("'" + str(string) + "' is not a valid Programm Code. Expected: eg. '440'.") 

        result = AbstractProgrammCode(int(string.strip()))
        logging.getLogger(__name__).debug("ProgrammCode '" + str(result.name) + "' created.")
        return result
```

**"Concrete" Enum in consumer project**

```
from lib.abstract_programm_code import AbstractProgrammCode

class ProgrammCode(AbstractProgrammCode):
    P440 = 440
    P431 = 431
    P441 = 441
    P455 = 455
```

**Error message**

```
code = ProgrammCode.create_with(str(440))
```

```
tests/re_v1/decision/decider_test.py:100: in __create_dto
    code = ProgrammCode.create_with(str(programm_nr))
__app__/re_v1/programm/abstract_programm_code.py:11: in create_with
    result = AbstractProgrammCode(int(string.strip()))
/usr/lib/python3.9/enum.py:360: in __call__
    return cls.__new__(cls, value)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

cls = <enum 'AbstractProgrammCode'>, value = 440

    def __new__(cls, value):
        # all enum instances are actually created during class construction
        # without calling this method; this method is called by the metaclass'
        # __call__ (i.e. Color(3) ), and by pickle
        if type(value) is cls:
            # For lookups like Color(Color.RED)
            return value
        # by-value search for a matching enum member
        # see if it's in the reverse mapping (for hashable values)
        try:
            return cls._value2member_map_[value]
        except KeyError:
            # Not found, no need to do long O(n) search
            pass
        except TypeError:
            # not there, now do long search -- O(n) behavior
            for member in cls._member_map_.values():
                if member._value_ == value:
                    return member
        # still not found -- try _missing_ hook
        try:
            exc = None
            result = cls._missing_(value)
        except Exception as e:
            exc = e
            result = None
        try:
            if isinstance(result, cls):
                return result
            else:
                ve_exc = ValueError("%r is not a valid %s" % (value, cls.__qualname__))
                if result is None and exc is None:
>                   raise ve_exc
E                   ValueError: 440 is not a valid AbstractProgrammCode

/usr/lib/python3.9/enum.py:678: ValueError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error disappear when you replace @staticmethod by @classmethod and you use cls parameter instead of AbstractProgrammCode

```
import logging
from enum import Enum

class AbstractProgrammCode(Enum):
    
    
    @classmethod
    def create_with(cls,string: str):
    
        if not string or not string.strip().isnumeric():
            raise ValueError("'" + str(string) + "' is not a valid Programm Code. Expected: eg. '440'.") 
       
        result = cls(int(string.strip()))
        logging.getLogger(__name__).debug("ProgrammCode '" + str(result.name) + "' created.")
        
        return result
```

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for pointing this out to a java programmer